# Need suggestions on AngularJS $routeProvider for login page and member page in same SPA

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Login page** (partial/login.html)

- Includes a login form that will be shown using (ng-view)

**Member page** (partial/main.html)

- Includes a nav bar
- Includes the main container for contents (ng-view)

Question is how can I "hide" the nav bar in the Login page and only show it after the user has logged in?
Both my login page and member page shared the same index.html ng-view.

Sample **index.html**

```
<html ng-app>

<!-- LOGGED IN, SHOW NAV AND CONTENT-->
<div ng-if="logged" class="main_container">

  <nav>
  ... nav bar contents here...
  </nav>

  <div class="main_container">
    <div ng-view>... show partials ...</div>
  </div>

</div><!-- end of LOGGED IN, SHOW NAV AND CONTENT-->

<!-- NOT LOGGED IN -->
<div ng-if="!logged" class="main_container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>

<footer>...</footer
</html>
```

Tried using *ng-if*, but controllers are being called twice. May I know what others alternatives do I have?

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: make a plunker so that we can see your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-view` should only be used once.

`$routeProvider` will help you load different view when `$route` changed, like:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when('/login', {
    controller: 'LoginController',
    templateUrl: 'partial/login.html'
  })
  .when('/', {
    controller: 'MainController',
    templateUrl: 'partial.main.html'
  });
});
```

So now you only need to show/hide nav by your root controller, which can be injected in more top `div` in your page.

```
<div ng-controller="RootController" class="main_container">
  <nav ng-if="logged">
  ... nav bar contents here...
  </nav>
  <div class="main_container">
    <div ng-view>... show partials ...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Next, you can set/get `logged` in `RootController` or its child controllers. Notice setting variables in child controller may create a new variable in child scope, so I suggest add a function in `RootController` to set `logged` or use a service/factory to store logged status.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the **ng-show** directive, with the help of a function inside your controller.

```
  <nav ng-show="loginStatus()">
  ... nav bar contents here...
  </nav>
```

And inside your controller, you can add a function as such...

```
$scope.loginStatus= function() {
    return $loginVariable;
}
```

Use the loginVariable to return true/false based on the users login status.

Similarly, you can use the **ng-hide** directive to hide the main_container div.